# how can I display error when the pattern does not fit my pattern using Form builder

Tags: regex, html, symfony, fosuserbundle

**Update:**

I'am trying to add a pattern to ChangePaswwordForm of FOSUserBundle and I want to display a specific message error , I tried to override the Form by adding the attribute 'oninvalide' but in this case the error shows up only when we field is empty and it does not work when the password doesn't fit my pattern.here is the code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password','pattern' => "[A-Za-z0-9]{4,}",
            'attr'=>array( 'oninvalid'=>"setCustomValidity(',,Hi')")),

        'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password_confirmation','pattern' => "[A-Za-z0-9]{4,}"),

        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    ));
}
```

Comment: You seem to miss the trailing delimiter, try `'/[0-9]{10}/'`, or just `'[0-9]{10}'`

Comment: In this case, you are missing trailing delimiter in your regular expression. But if all you want is to display custom error message I would recommend you this approach http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UserPassword.html#basic-usage

Comment: now it works Thank you ! but when I add "attr" in order to override the default message error the pattern doesn't work.